# How to move text box values from the rightmost textbox to its immediate text box to the left until all the text boxes are filled?

Tags: javascript, css, html

Please see the picture. 
There are 7 text boxes where only one character can be input

4 conditions are to be fulfilled

1. The last text box - the rightmost/seventh textbox will be input first, then the sixth one will be filled , then the fifth and so on
2. Then the rightmost/seventh textbox value will shift (left shift) to the sixth and in this way values will shift until all 7 fields are filled
3. If we place the cursor on any other element except the last/seventh/rightmost it will move the cursor to the rightmost .
4. There will be backspace function which will delete the rightmost, ie. the the seventh field will be deleted the first field value will move to second, second to third , sixth to seventh , like this , a right shift will occur in this way all elements are to be deleted

[image]

**My Code**

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>JavaScript to automatically move from one field to another   field</title>

<script type="text/javascript">


 function movetoPrev(current, nextFieldID)
 {
  if (current.value.length >= current.maxLength)
    {
    document.getElementById(nextFieldID).focus();
    }
  }




function movetoLast(current)
{
  if (current.value.length < 1)
    {
    document.getElementById("seventh").focus();
    }
  }



  function isNumber(evt)
{
evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;

var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;

if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
{
    alert("Please enter number");
    return false;
}

return true;
 }


</script>

</head>

<body>

<form class="frm1">


<input class="inputs" type="text" id="first" size="1" pattern="[0-9]" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onclick="movetoLast(this)" maxlength="1" />

<input class="inputs" type="text" id="second" size="1" pattern="[0-9]" onkeyup="movetoPrev(this, 'first')" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onclick="movetoLast(this)" maxlength="1" />

<input class="inputs" type="text" id="third" size="1" pattern="[0-9]" onkeyup="movetoPrev(this, 'second')" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onclick="movetoLast(this)" maxlength="1" />

<input class="inputs" type="text" id="fourth" size="1" pattern="[0-9]" onkeyup="movetoPrev(this, 'third')" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onclick="movetoLast(this)" maxlength="1" />

<input class="inputs" type="text" id="fifth" size="1" pattern="[0-9]" onkeyup="movetoPrev(this, 'fourth')" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onclick="movetoLast(this)" maxlength="1" />

<input class="inputs" type="text" id="sixth" size="1" pattern="[0-9]" onkeyup="movetoPrev(this, 'fifth')" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onclick="movetoLast(this)" maxlength="1" />

<input class="inputs" type="text" id="seventh" size="1" pattern="[0-9]" onkeyup="movetoPrev(this, 'sixth')" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" maxlength="1" />
```

Answer (score 1):

So you have seven inputs, you want to be able to enter numbers only, and you want to have the last input be the only editable one. See if this does what you're looking for:

```js
var myInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var myEditable = document.getElementById("seventh");
for (var i = 0; i < myInputs.length; i++) {
  myInputs[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("seventh").focus();
  })
}

myEditable.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt) {
  /****
   *  A few things are handled here: we can check if
   *  the input is a numeric, and we can check if the input
   *  is a backspace. Nothing else is allowed.
   ****/
  if (evt.which == 8) {
    // If a backspace has been pressed, move all the input
    //  values one field UP.
    myEditable.blur();
    for (var i = myInputs.length - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
      myInputs[i].value = myInputs[i - 1].value;
    }
    myInputs[0].value = "";
  } else if (evt.which >= 48 && evt.which <= 59) {
    // Here, we have a number. Everything gets bumped to the LEFT
    if (myInputs[0].value == "") {
      for (var i = 0; i < myInputs.length - 1; i++) {
        myInputs[i].value = myInputs[i + 1].value;
      }
      myEditable.value = String.fromCharCode(evt.which);
    }
  } else {
    console.log("You did something else...");
  }
})
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="first" size="1" maxlength="1" />
  <input type="text" id="second" size="1" maxlength="1" />
  <input type="text" id="third" size="1" maxlength="1" />
  <input type="text" id="fourth" size="1" maxlength="1" />
  <input type="text" id="fifth" size="1" maxlength="1" />
  <input type="text" id="sixth" size="1" maxlength="1" />
  <input type="text" id="seventh" size="1" maxlength="1" />
</form>
```

Yes, it's javascript only. Also, I've moved the listeners so that they're not hard-coded to the inputs. Other than that, I think it's doing what you want.

One problem I haven't been able to work around (and the reason you have to re-click the seventh field after backspace) is that, if the seventh field has focus, it won't display the new value after backspace. If I blur it it works fine. Strange.

Comment: I can't edit any other fields but the right-most. I believe the OP wanted to be able to edit right-to-left as the right-most are filled.
"The last text box - the rightmost/seventh textbox will be input first, then the sixth one will be filled , then the fifth and so on"

Comment: From what I'm reading, the input is expected to only happen on the rightmost input, and as more input occurs, the values are populated in a right-to-left direction (and backspace reverses the process). clicking in any field moves the focus to the rightmost, and all editing happens there.

Comment: It is a little confusing, given the wording, but I think we've got something  close to on-track. Heh.

Comment: Note:: `event.key` is not supported in Chrome 49 or Safari 10.
That's why it wasn't working for me.

Comment: reworking it (playing with a fiddle) with event.which -- it's not a huge change, but it should still work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133921/discussion-between-snowmonkey-and-bobjoe).

Comment: @Snowmonkey it is working in jsfiddle but not working in chrome

Comment: @bobjoe it is working in jsfiddle but not working in chrome

Comment: @Snowmonkey how to make it working in chrome , using chrome 55

Comment: @bobjoe how to make it working in chrome , using chrome 55

Comment: I'm on chrome 55, working fine. When you say 'how to make it working in chrome', what exactly is it not doing?